# In Grails, how to get the granted authorities (roles) of a user that isn't logged in

Tags: groovy, grails, spring-security, roles, cas

In Grails, you can use springSecurityService.principal.authorities to get the logged in user's roles from CAS.

I've been doing this for sometime now, but for the first time, I need to be able to check the authorities of other users. I need to know if a different user had an admin role than the one I'm currently logged into.

I've checked the SpringSecurityService class, but none of them seem helpful in achieving this.

Is there some class or method that Spring Security provides that can return these?

Answer (score 0):

What's your `authority.className` configuration? If you set up your proejct using quickstart command: `grails s2-quickstart com.yourapp User Role` descibed in:
https://grails.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/4.0.x/index.html#s2-quickstart
then your Roles mapped on Users will exist in `user_role` table. Simply just check out which roles belong to specific user basing on data from this table.

Comment: for example: `UserRole.findAllByUser(user)*.role`